# JavaScript abort task if it`s taking more than xxx seconds

Tags: javascript, multithreading

I understand that JavaScript is a single-threaded language but I was wondering if there is any way to stop the execution of a long task if it`s taking too long.

I am working on a calculator and I use a lot of 3rd party libraries to perform calculations. Sometimes calculations can take too long and I want to be able to time-out, stop the calculation, and show an error or something.

So far I discovered that I can achieve this with WebWorkers but I don`t really like using them and they also introduce some overhead.

Is there any better way of achieving this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement a "function timeout" in Javascript - not just the 'setTimeout'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778718/how-to-implement-a-function-timeout-in-javascript-not-just-the-settimeout)

Comment: No :( Unfortunately none of these actually provide a good way of timing out a function.

Comment: What are you defining as "good" here?  Specifically, why don't these answers work for you?

Comment: I tried it with a function that has a while loop that loops for 10 seconds for example, and besides the worker's solution (I already know about this and I am trying to avoid using it), the rest of the solutions are not able to terminate the function.