# Return a default value after a timeout

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have a long running function call and I want to limit its execution time.

```
function f(a,b,c) {
  // some long-running code
  return value;
}

var val = f(a,b,c); // this call should be limited to x milliseconds
                    // if the function doesn't return we continue with a fall-back value (which is available in the calling method)
```

How can I call this code with a timeout, so that if the execution finishes it will return `value` and otherwise it will return a default value?

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778718) but it's 9 years old and I couldn't get the most recent answer  (the one using Promises) modified for my use-case. Is there a simpler way to achieve this?

Comment: The worker approach is the only one that will work. Use the code in that answer, and if the timeout is reached without a message from the worker, use the fallback value

Comment: This is possible to solve with Promises. I have an answer, please re-open so I can post it.